# Using Galera-Replication, what's the use in having a GTID associated with your backup?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

On the topic of using a backupscripts the documentation for galera-cluster states that:

> You can use backups of this kind to recover data, but they are
>   insufficient for use in recovering nodes to a well-defined state.

I struggle to understand what is meant by a well defined state and how this state could differ from a state where we just recovered our cluster with a backup we created with mysqldump.

Having the cluster in a "well defined state" as in having a GTID with a seqno bigger than zero won't be of any use if the changes to the other nodes can't be done via Incremental State Transfer (IST) --> saving time and traffic.

If the cluster is in such a dire state that we actually decide to recover from a backup, wouldn't there be a need to

a) assign a new clusterID and a seqno of 0 to the first node and

b) get the nodes back online via a state snapshot transfer anyway?

Comment: Please provide url of that quote.

Comment: http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/galera-documentation.pdf      Chapter 21, Second paragraph